# Draw two images onto HTML canvas in a specific order

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've written a function which draws two images, *textBG* and *strap*, onto a canvas. TextBG is a background, whilst strap is a logo to go on top of the background.

Annoyingly, however, there doesn't seem to be any specific order in which the two images are drawn onto the canvas, so the background will often be drawn on top of the logo.

Can anyone help me determine a way of ensuring that the first image, textBG, is loaded before the strap image, and therefore doesn't obscure it?

**Javascript**

```
function addTextBg(){

    var colourInput = document.getElementById("bgColour").value;
    if(colourInput > 2){
        var colour = 'red';
    }else if(colourInput > 1){
        var colour = 'pink';
    }else if(colourInput > 0){
        var colour = 'blue';
    }else{
        var colour = 'white';
    }
    var opacity = document.getElementById("bgOpacity").value;
    var size = document.getElementById("bgSize").value;
    var alignment = document.getElementById("bgAlign").value;
    if(colourInput > 0){
        var strapColour = 'white';
    }else{
        var strapColour = 'black';
    }

    var textBg = new Image();
    textBg.src = 'images/text-bg/'+colour+'-'+opacity+'-'+size+'-'+alignment+'.png';
    textBg.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(textBg, 0, 0);
    }

    var strap = new Image();
    strap.src = 'images/straps/strap-'+strapColour+'-'+alignment+'-'+size+'.png';
    strap.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(strap, 0, 0);
    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var BGloaded=false;
var logoloaded=false;

textBG.onload=function()
{
    BGloaded=true;
    tryToDraw();
}

strap.onload=function()
{
    logoloaded=true;
    tryToDraw();
}

function tryToDraw()
{
    if (BGloaded && logoloaded)
    {
        context.drawImage(textBg, 0, 0); //draw it first
        context.drawImage(strap, 0, 0); //and then draw that!
    }
}
```

Another option: (proposed by markE)

```
var loaded=0;

textBG.onload=function()
{
    loaded++; //does the same as loaded+=1
    tryToDraw();
}

strap.onload=function()
{
    loaded++;
    tryToDraw();
}

function tryToDraw()
{
    if (loaded==2) //the total amount of images
    {
        context.drawImage(textBg, 0, 0); //draw it first
        context.drawImage(strap, 0, 0); //and then draw that!
    }
}
```

I hope i could help! =)

Comment: Upvote! You can make your solution less "variable dependent" by using a counter instead of `var BGloaded` and `var logoadded`. F.ex: `var counter=2` since you have 2 images to preload. And then `if(--counter>0){return;}` in `tryToDraw`. :-)

Comment: Edit: added your idea! =)